# SQL - calculate consumption of materials based on recipe

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm not sure how to ask my question, so I'll explain what I'm trying to do: I'm building an app in Delphi XE, which should calculate the consumption of raw materials, based on products recipes and orders.

I have 5 tables: Orders, OrdersContent, Products, Raw Materials and Recipes. Each order is composed of a few products, and each product has it's own recipe of raw materials.

I already summed up all products from all orders using sql in Query1.
This is the command for Query1:

```
    select Products.Price,
    OrdersContent.ID_Product, sum(OrdersContent.QNT) as QNT_Sum,
    (Products.Price * sum(OrdersContent.QNT)) as Value
    from Orders, OrdersContent, Products
    where Orders.ID = OrdersContent.ID_Order
    and Products.ID = OrdersContent.ID_Product
    group by
    OrdersContent.ID_Product, Products.Price
```

This returns:

```
    |Price  | ID_Product | QNT_Sum | Value |
    ----------------------------------------
    |  2    |   122521   |  150    |   300 |
    |  10   |   366547   |   10    |   100 |
    |  xxx  |   xxxxxx   |  xxx    |  xxxxx|
```

It's exactly what I want.

So now I'm wondering if there's a way to calculate the raw materials consumption also using sql, as the only other way I know how to do this is to iterate through the whole Query1 and calculate raw materials consumption for each record(product) individually, add it to a new table and then sum up the results, which is very time consuming.

I'm pretty sure there must be a more efficient way to do this, but have no clue as to how or where to search how to do it. I'm not asking for the code, but some pointers or links to tutorials or examples.

I hope I'm clear enough, if not please do ask for more info.

Comment: Did you mean QNT_Sum * Price? to produce Value?

Comment: Actually, I tried with QNT_Sum * Price, but it said that QNT_Sum has no default value. It does, however, work like this. And it makes sense, as QNT_Sum is not a column in my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Raw Materials and Recipe to your FROM clause with the appropriate joins. Group by raw materials. Remove id_product and price from your group by statement. Change the aggregation in your select to sum(products.price*orderscontent.qnt).

I'm guessing at your column names in Recipes and Raw Materials but here's the general idea.

```
    select Recipes.ID_RAW_MATERIALS, 
           sum(OrdersContent.QNT) as QNT_Sum,
           sum(Products.Price * OrdersContent.QN)) as Value 
      from Orders, OrdersContent, Products, Recipes, RawMaterials 
     where Orders.ID = OrdersContent.ID_Order 
       and Products.ID = OrdersContent.ID_Product 
       and Recipes.ID_PRODUCT = Products.ID 
       AND Recipes.ID_RAW_MATERIAL = Rawmaterials.ID 
     group by Recipes.ID_RAW_MATERIALS
```